# How can we return only unique records from table?

Tags: mysql

I am having a table structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
  `Source` VARCHAR(20),
  `Destination` VARCHAR(20),
  `Distance` Integer
);

INSERT INTO yourTable
  (`Source`, `Destination`, `Distance`)
VALUES
  ('Buffalo', 'Rochester', 2200),
  ('Yonkers', 'Syracuse', 1400),
  ('Cheektowaga', 'Schenectady', 600),
  ('Rochester', 'Buffalo', 2200)
```

How can we return only unique records for example as 'Buffalo' and 'Rochester' are present in 1 & 4 rows so one should be taken while retrieving.

I tried writing this query but here source and destination values are not correct for 3 rows `Schenectady Cheektowaga`

```
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(Source, Destination) as Source,  LEAST(Source, Destination) AS Destination, Distance
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: You can use group by with condition of your select.

Comment: Your query does return only unique rows. But it doesn't ensure that the source and destionation stay in the same columns, because it alphabetizes them to ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries that you combine with `UNION`. One query returns the rows that are already unique, the other removes the duplicate from the rows that are duplicated in the other direction.

```
SELECT t1.Source, t1.Destination, t1.Distance
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.Source = t2.Destination AND t1.Destination = t2.Source
WHERE t2.Source IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT GREATEST(Source, Destination) AS s,  LEAST(Source, Destination) AS d, MAX(Distance) AS Distance
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY s, d
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFhTyECvtD3evhsL1bXgL/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from yourTable group by greatest(source,destination);
```

Comment: Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.yourTable.Source' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Try adding an aggregated column to the select clause: `select *, count(*) from yourTable group by greatest(source,destination);`